# Swift. Page based application. Immediately updating of UIViewController after update ModelController

Tags: ios, swift

I Created Page Based Application from Apples template. I have a function in `RootViewController` for updating my `ModelController` after receiving a data from web server:

```
    func updateMC() {
        if let mc = getModelControllerWithLatestData() {
            self._modelController = mc

            let startingViewController: DataViewController = self.modelController.viewControllerAtIndex(1, storyboard: self.storyboard!)!
            let viewControllers = [startingViewController]
//            self.pageViewController!.setViewControllers(viewControllers, direction: .Forward, animated: false, completion: {done in })
            self.pageViewController!.setViewControllers(viewControllers, direction: .Forward, animated: true, completion: nil)

            self.pageViewController!.dataSource = self.modelController
            self.pageViewController!.didMoveToParentViewController(self)

            println("updateMC")
        }
    }
```

But new Data appearing on the screen after 10-15 seconds after updating _modelController.

How can I fix the issue?

P.S. I posted src of the `RootViewController`, hope this would be helpful: https://gist.github.com/stillfinder/d3ec7a57c73569411ff5

Comment: Check if the code after executing getModelControllerWithLatestData is executing in UI thread or in a background thread

Comment: in background thread. 
let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(serverUrl!) {(data, response, error) in
...
task.resume()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That happened because a background thread can't modify the UI. Only the UI Thread should modify that add this code, to run the modifiers in the main thread

`dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {}`

```
func updateMC() {
    if let mc = getModelControllerWithLatestData() {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {

            self._modelController = mc

            let startingViewController: DataViewController = self.modelController.viewControllerAtIndex(1, storyboard: self.storyboard!)!
            let viewControllers = [startingViewController]
//          self.pageViewController!.setViewControllers(viewControllers, direction: .Forward, animated: false, completion: {done in })
            self.pageViewController!.setViewControllers(viewControllers, direction: .Forward, animated: true, completion: nil)

            self.pageViewController!.dataSource = self.modelController
            self.pageViewController!.didMoveToParentViewController(self)

            println("updateMC")
        }
    }
}
```